# return by reference/pointer of a static local variable

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, unordered-map

I'm confused by why a static unordered_map gets cleared if I get it by reference but not if I get it by pointer...  (you can execute the code here: http://cpp.sh/4ondg)

Is it because when a reference go out of scope, its destructor gets called? if so, then what's the 2nd get function would get?

```
class MyTestClass {
    public:
    static std::unordered_map<int, int>& getMap() {
        static std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
        return map;
    }
    static std::unordered_map<int, int>* getMapByPointer() {
        static std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
        return &map;
    }

};


int main()
{
    // By reference
    {
        auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMap();
        std::cout << theMap.size() << std::endl;
        theMap[5] = 3;
        std::cout << theMap.size() << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMap();
        std::cout << theMap.size() << std::endl;
        theMap[6] = 4;
        std::cout << theMap.size() << std::endl;
    }

    // By pointer
    {
        auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMapByPointer();
        std::cout << theMap->size() << std::endl;
        (*theMap)[5] = 3;
        std::cout << theMap->size() << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMapByPointer();
        std::cout << theMap->size() << std::endl;
        (*theMap)[6] = 4;
        std::cout << theMap->size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine if you did this `std::unordered_map<int, int>* j = &(getMap())` -- what object would `j` point to?

Comment: `auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMap();` makes a copy of the map. To safe a reference, use `auto&`. [Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L5T1zSXriVZw138P)

Comment: again a soul, hit by `auto` keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMap();
```

The type of `theMap` is deduced to be `std::unordered_map<int, int>` – not a reference. Therefore, the reference returned by the function call is *copied* into the local variable `theMap`; when you modify `theMap`, you're only modifying this copy.

To store a reference, declare it as `auto&`:

```
auto& theMap = MyTestClass::getMap();
```

Then you'll be modifying the original object as intended.

Comment: Plus one because you explained how to fix it :D

Comment: heh you got to it before I could, very nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You're unintentionally copying the static map when you assign it to a local variable. In:

```
auto theMap = MyTestClass::getMap();
```

`auto` is deduced as `std::unordered_map<int, int>`, not `std::unordered_map<int, int>&`, which causes a new object to be copy-initialized from the returned reference. So, `theMap` is a completely separate object from the static map.

The pointer version doesn't have this problem because the type is deduced to a pointer, so the only thing being copied is the pointer value itself, which always points to the same (static) object.